# Footer is not visible in my website HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

Please help me! Footer is not visible on my website.I tried on inserting "position: absolute; top: 50px; left:100px;" however it's not working. I am using HTML/CSS. Can someone fix this and help me.

Here is the link of my code:
https://code.sololearn.com/WzCJV6cF5ees/?ref=app

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top` instead of `top` on your `.contentarea` - with `margin-top: 450px` it's moved down from its original position by 450px, but still occopies the orignal space and thereby overlaps the footer (which is *not*  moved).

Comment: this did not worked. The navigation bar is positioned at the bottom while the outerfooter is positioned at the top. Please help